# When pandas reads a large file by read_csv methods. IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

Tags: python, pandas

**Env:**

```
Package                       Version

----------------------------- ---------

backports.functools-lru-cache 1.5

beautifulsoup4                4.6.0

certifi                       2018.4.16

chardet                       3.0.4

cycler                        0.10.0

Django                        1.11.14

et-xmlfile                    1.0.1

future                        0.16.0

googlemaps                    2.5.1

idna                          2.6

jdcal                         1.4

jenkinsapi                    0.3.6

Jinja2                        2.10

kiwisolver                    1.0.1

lxml                          4.2.1

MarkupSafe                    1.0

matplotlib                    2.2.2

numpy                         1.14.3

openpyxl                      2.5.3

pandas                        0.23.0

pip                           10.0.1

psycopg2                      2.7.5

pymongo                       3.7.0

pyparsing                     2.2.0

python-dateutil               2.7.3

pytz                          2018.4

PyYAML                        3.12

requests                      2.18.4

scipy                         1.1.0

seaborn                       0.8.1

selenium                      3.12.0

setuptools                    18.2

six                           1.11.0

urllib3                       1.22

web.py                        0.40.dev1

wheel                         0.31.1

xmldiff                       1.1.1
```

OS: Windows 10

Python 2.7

**Description:**

When I read a large csv file test.csv (1.15G) by method `read_csv`, the python throws some exceptions.

Code below:

```
 file =os.path.join(DATA_PATH, "test.csv")

  test_chunks = pd.read_csv(file,iterator=True,  engine="python",error_bad_lines=False, sep=',')

  test_chunk = test_chunks.get_chunk(5)
```

The interpreter throws some exceptions:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/work_code/QA_tools/autogencases/utils/csvReader.py", line 149, in <module>
    error_bad_lines=False, sep=',') 

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 678, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 440, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 787, in __init__
    self._make_engine(self.engine)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1024, in _make_engine
    self._engine = klass(self.f, **self.options)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 2089, in __init__
    self.columns, self.num_original_columns = self._infer_columns()

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 2359, in _infer_columns
    line = self._buffered_line()

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 2530, in _buffered_line
    return self._next_line()

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 2635, in _next_line
    orig_line = self._next_iter_line(row_num=self.pos + 1)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 2695, in _next_iter_line
    return next(self.data)

IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

But I check the permissions of test.csv is OK, and the permissions of its parent path is OK too. Meanwhile, there is another csv file in the same folder obtaining the same permissions which can be read correctly, and the only difference is that it is only 135M.

Comment: Is there anyone can help me ?

Comment: have you tried moving the file somewhere else? are you sure the permissions are fine for the user that's running Python?

Comment: My eyes glaze over looking at walls of unformatted text...

Comment: @AshishAcharya Thank you your answer. It give me some idea. I found that it has opened by Excel background. When I killed the Excel, the issue has been solved.

Comment: ah yes, good ol' Excel locks :)